# App Install History on Android

Tags: android

Does anyone know if there's a way to access past app installs via the sdk?  I want to be able to get a list of all the apps users have downloaded from the Market.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [PackageManager](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html). This class contains `getInstalledApplications()` and `getInstalledPackages()` which can be used to get information about installed applications. I haven't tried these, but if they don't work you can also try `queryIntentActivities()` with the `ACTION_MAIN` intent as an argument to get information about all activities that can be launched through the launcher.

When you get a set of all applications that are installed on the device, you can try to remove the pre-installed Android applications to get the list of user installed applications. I guess that the pre-installed applications are somewhat static so you should be able to get a list of them easily (like from a newly created Android emulator).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hm. That'll be mostly helpful. Know of a way to get apps that were installed then then removed? Seems unlikely, but I'm hopeful.