# How To Launch Quick office app in my android Project?

Tags: android, skype

I want to Launch Quickoffice app in my android application and how get package name of it.

i use this source to launch Skype :

```
enter code here
PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
            Intent skype = packageManager
                    .getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.skype.raider");

            startActivity(skype);
```

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664353/how-do-i-start-another-application-downloaded-or-preinstalled-from-an-activity

Answer (score 1):

From google playstore you can get the required package names

In this case QuickOfficePro has **com.qo.android.am3**

Google play store lists the package names as the id parameter in their URLs `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.qo.android.am3`

By the way make sure you handle errors properly, in case the user does not have the application you want installed.

Also there are a few versions of quick office on Play Store, and all of them will have different package names.

Comment: how this package in playstore,I can't find it..     https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.qo.android.am3&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNvbS5xby5hbmRyb2lkLmFtMyJd

Comment: check the URL

it is /details?id= **packagename** 

everything after that can be ignored. infact you can delete everything after that and the URL will still work. like `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.qo.android.am3`

Comment: can you getting full link ( /details?id )   ...i dont know find it

Comment: `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.qo.android.am3&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNvbS5xby5hbmRyb2lkLmFtMyJd`. This is the link you have. if you read it the part after `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=` **com.packge.name** `&otherstuff`

Answer (score 1):

Go to playstore on web.

locate and app you want to open, see the URL.
There are 2 quick office apps
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.qo.android.am3

and

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.qo.android.tablet.am

last section is app id.

Comment: excuse me freinds,,,, I dont know to resolve this problems to find package name in playstore.now i want to find package name google chrome?